# how do i install Video Codec on ubuntu 12.04 ?

Tags: package-management, video, codecs

On my machine mp3 files are playing perfectly . I want to downlaod video codec for playing populer types of format ! like mp4 3gp mkv flv avi ..etc . is there any way to play those files without installing ubuntu restricted extras ? i wanna download just video codec and nothing else .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pop into your Software Centre or Synaptic and search for 'gstreamer0.10' and a list of available codecs will appear, select the plugins for good bad and ugly to install and that should give you all available movie/audio formats...